# Project Euler #27 Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Project Euler Problem #27 is as follows:

> Euler discovered the remarkable quadratic formula:
>
> n² + n + 41
>
> It turns out that the formula will produce 40 primes for the
>   consecutive values n = 0 to 39. However, when n = 40, 402 + 40 + 41 =
>   40(40 + 1) + 41 is divisible by 41, and certainly when n = 41, 41² +
>   41 + 41 is clearly divisible by 41.
>
> The incredible formula  n² − 79n + 1601 was discovered, which produces
>   80 primes for the consecutive values n = 0 to 79. The product of the
>   coefficients, −79 and 1601, is −126479.
>
> Considering quadratics of the form:
>
> n² + an + b, where |a| < 1000 and |b| < 1000
>
> where |n| is the modulus/absolute value of n e.g. |11| = 11 and |−4| =
>   4 Find the product of the coefficients, a and b, for the quadratic
>   expression that produces the maximum number of primes for consecutive
>   values of n, starting with n = 0.

And this is my solution:

```
from math import sqrt, fabs

def eSieve(rnge):
    rootedrange = int(sqrt(rnge))
    mydict = dict([(_, True) for _ in range(2, rootedrange)])
    for i in range(2, rootedrange):
        if mydict[i] == True:
            for j in range(i**2, rnge, i):
                mydict[j] = False
    mylist = []
    for key in mydict.keys():
        if mydict[key] is True:
            mylist.append(key)
    return mylist

primes = eSieve(87400)

def isPrime(n):
    i = 0
    while primes[i] <= n:
        if primes[i] == n: return True
        i+=1
    return False

arange = 0
brange = 0
nrange = 0
for a in range(-1000, 1001):
    for b in range(-1000, 1001):
        n = 0
        formula = n*n + a*n + b
        print(formula)
        while(isPrime(fabs(formula))):
            n+=1

        if n > nrange:
            arange = a
            brange = b
            crange = c

print(arange * brange)
```

I do not know why is it continuously throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\ProjectEuler\p27.py", line 33, in <module>
    while(isPrime(fabs(formula))):
  File "D:\Programming\ProjectEuler\p27.py", line 20, in isPrime
    while primes[i] <= n:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone tell where and how is my program getting out of lists range? It's very abnormal. Why is this happening?

Comment: For what `n` and what `i` do you get the error?

Comment: The very first ones @hlt

Comment: If `primes[0]` throws an `IndexError`, then `primes` is empty.

Comment: @hlt not possible; checked it.

Comment: Two close votes for lacking a minimal, complete, and verifiable example? Really now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what happens if you want to see if 1000000 is a prime:

```
i = 0
while primes[i] <= n:
    if primes[i] == n: return True
    i+=1

return False
```

None of the sieved primes is larger than 1000000 so your `while` condition is never fulfilled. First rule of Python is to **never use `while` loop** (except when you cannot use any other loop). Here you can easily replace it with `for`:

```
for i in primes:
    if i == n:
        return True

return False
```

But this is exactly what the `in` operator is set to replace:

```
return n in primes
```

In addition for your `isPrime` reimplementing the Python core feature `n in primes`, the
`item in list`  gets slower than `item in set` as the number of items grows.

Thus for fastest code with almost least typing you can do:

```
>>> primes = eSieve(87400)
>>> prime_set = set(primes)
>>> 13 in prime_set
True
>>> # or if you want a function:
>>> is_prime = prime_set.__contains__
>>> is_prime(13)
True
```

[`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) magic method of the `set` returns true if the given value is in the `set` - this is much faster using it directly than wrapping `in` operator in a function.

Answer (score 0):

If `isPrime(n)` should return whether `n` is in the previously created list `primes`, then you can easily write:

```py
def isPrime(n):
    return n in primes
```

(Your solution fails, because your prime list is too short for `n = 1000`. The largest prime is 293, thus the `while` condition is always fulfilled. But after a while you want to compare `primes[62]` with `n`, which is out of range.)